# JDBC MVC - Ways of sharing DB connection instances in Repositories methods

Tags: java, model-view-controller, repository

I'm building an MVC based web application, each Aggregate of Models has it's own Repository. The repositories fetch the data from a MySQL database.

I'm having an hard time deciding how to implement the various repositories methods, mainly because I want to be able to perform sequential queries in the same database connection (as opposed to creating a new connection in each method body, and closing it at the end of the method).

One way to share a db connection instance between two sequential repository methods, would be to pass an instance of an already created DB Connection (which is created outside the repository) as an argument for the repository method.
Obviously, This implementation smells totally wrong design-wise.

A different approach would be having a singleton DB Connection Pool or a Factory of some sort which the repositories will use, and have the option for specifically create a new connection if desired.

I was wondering if you guys have any other design tips for the above issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all solved. Don't write it yourself. Use a connection pooling library that provides a DataSource implementation like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). That takes care of connection reuse. Use [Spring's JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-core) to handle all the opening and closing for you. Then apply [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) on top of it, and you'll effectively get a connection-per-request.

Comment: Can you explain in a few words why would I need to use anything other then DBCP, which takes care of the connection re-using issue?

Comment: DBCP is only a connection pool that can give you back the same connection(s) upon multiple getConnection() calls. Using just that, you'd still have the problem of how to use the same connection across multiple persistence methods.

Comment: Got it, I still think that for my purpose it'll fit well. Thanks again for the great info

Comment: Once I receive a connection from the DBCP, should I use connection.close() like I would normally do once I finish using it on one method of my repository? If so, am I not missing the point of actually "sharing" this connection again? wouldn't this action will force the connection pool to create another connection instance on the sequential repository method call?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to say. DBCP is only half the solution. You also need to use something like Spring for resource management, which is the other half.